# Why does this method return a boolean?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

Why return bool from SetProperty? It's not used.

This is from boilerplate code coming out of a Xamarin.Forms template.

It's not used in inherited classes either.

---

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore,
                                  T value,
                                  [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
                                  Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals (backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: It's sometimes useful to be able to write things like `if (SetProperty(ref backingStore, value)) { OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OtherProperty)); }` in your property's setter. This ensures that the extra notification for `OtherProperty` is only raised if that property has actually changed

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted the whole class:

Comment: That doesn't change what I said

Comment: Now it may. I posted the full class.

Comment: Nope. It can still be useful to check whether the value of a property changed from its setter, and a nice way to do that is by returning such a bool from `SetProperty`. The fact that you haven't happened to find someone doing this doesn't mean that *nobody* does it.

Comment: Please post answers, not comments. Comments are for requesting clarification, answers are for... well, answers.

Comment: That's what I thought. I don't like "just in case" code. If it's not being used then don't introduce it. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: This sits in a base class, which may be used by anyone. This type of `SetProperty` is also very standard fodder in WPF, I'd be frankly surprised if I saw a `SetProperty` method which *didn't* return a bool -- I'd treat that as breaking the pattern, and wonder why

Answer (score 5):

The return value of this `SetProperty` method indicates if it has effectively changed its underlying backing field.

The `IsBusy` implementation doesn't use the return value of `SetProperty`, but in a derived class, which can access this protected SetProperty method, its return value could be used to perform additional specialized tasks.

By the way, I actually didn't expect the `BaseViewModel` class to have an `IsBusy` property with a public setter. As it is now, the outside world can determine if a `BaseViewModel` instance is busy or not. As I see it, that's somewhat strange.